# Are External LDAP referrals similar to a DNS Recursive or non recursive entry?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, adam, smime

I'm very familiar with DNS, but less so with LDAP.

In DNS I have the ability to delegate the CPU and IO load of referral chasing a given DNS query... or I can set `norecurse` and have the client perform those tasks (or not recurse at all)

My goal is to point my LDAP clients to a single corporate directory (AD or ADLS/ADAM) and then download SMIME certificates from my corporate directory,  `ldap.globaltrustpoint.com` ([link](https://www.globaltrustpoint.com/repository-list.jsp)), or other directories as I see fit.

I'm following [the directions here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978014.aspx) to add globaltrustpoint.com to the instance, and not sure how to test and see if LDAP referrals are more like a recursive or non-recursive query.

I'm also trying to figure out how to tell if this is a client-specific setting (Outlook, OSX mail, etc).

Any procedural help would be appreciated.